# Dependence of resonant frequency on the length of a ruler

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, frequency, resonance, structural-beam

Why does the resonance frequency of a ruler increase when the length is lower? I have a relationship from experimenting but I want to know why.

I have a vibration generator hooked up to the bottom of a secured ruler and test its resonance frequency. Why does it need a higher frequency when shorter in height?

Comment: Because the wavelength goes down.

Comment: yes but i get an exponential relationship for my ruler. using maths i should get (1/4L) = F but I think im missing something

Comment: Can you show us your data and the mismatching math so that it’s more clear?

Comment: yh added height on rhs and resonance on lhs

Comment: Are you saying that you are changing the length if a stick which is swinging like a pendulum?

Comment: The ruler is attached to a clamp at the bottom and connected to a vibration generator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The archetypal model for all oscillations is the [Mass on a Spring](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node3.html) for which the frequency can be written as $$f \propto \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$ where $k$ is stiffness term and $m$ is load or mass. $k$ is a measure of the restoring force which pulls the load back to the equilibrium position while $m$ represents a tendency to maintain the current motion - ie inertia.

For a [cantilever beam](https://materion.com/-/media/files/alloy/newsletters/technical-tidbits/issue-no-20--cantilever-beams---part-1-beam-stiffness.pdf) the stiffness $k$ is a measure of the force $F$ required to produce a given amount of deflection $x$ - ie $F=kx$. It is related to length by $k \propto 1/L^3$. The shorter the length the greater the force required to produce a given deflection. At the same time, for a fixed cross section the mass of the beam increases in direct proportion to its length : $m \propto L$. Combining these two factors we get $$f \propto \sqrt{\frac{1}{L^4}}=\frac{1}{L^2}$$

This relationship is confirmed by mathematical analysis of the [Free Oscillation of a Cantilever Beam](http://vlab.amrita.e$u/?sub=3&brch=175&sim=1080&cnt=1).

[image]

Your data follows a power law of the form $f \propto 1/L^n$ with $n = 2.28$ to a high degree of accuracy (see trendline equation in graph). This is in approximate agreement with the prediction $n=2$ from above.

The small discrepancy might be explained by [damping](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node10.html) in the form of frictional losses of kinetic energy which is transformed into thermal energy within the beam as it flexes. The frequency dependence $f \propto 1/L^2$ derived above is the natural frequency $f_0$ assuming that there is no damping. In the presence of damping (measured by factor $\gamma$ which is related to the fraction of energy lost in each cycle) the oscillation frequency is reduced to $f_1$ such that $$f_1^2=f_0^2-\gamma^2$$ This reduction in frequency is equivalent to an increase in the length of the beam, hence the increase in the exponent $n$.

Comment: Just looking back → with the formula k = f/x why is the force going to be consistent?

Comment: Different values of $k$ and $F$ apply for (i) a force applied at the end of the beam to deflect it by $x$ and (ii) shaking the beam to cause the same deflection $x$ at the end. However the two values of $k$ will vary with the length $L$ of the beam in the same way : $k \propto 1/L^3$.

Comment: Ok thankyou but would the moment of inertia also not affect this?

Comment: Yes the full formula includes the *area moment of inertia* of the cross-section of the beam. If the beam is uniform this is a constant. See eqn 4.6 in http://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=3&brch=175&sim=1080&cnt=1